# How to say "how are your Japanese studies going?"

Tags: words, expressions

I wanted to ask that to a friend that is also studying Japanese about how he is doing, and thought maybe asking "日本語の勉強はどうですか。" but I have no idea if it is correct. How do I say "how is (something) going?"

Comment: In a Japanese question, you ALWAYS need to tell the teller and receiver. It'll be different depending on hierarchy.

Comment: What do you mean by telling the teller and receiver?

Comment: Who say that? toward who? It'll be different if it's a student to another student or different hierarchy. I say that because your sentence seems too polite/unnatural for student-student conversation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. You can also say 日本語の勉強、どう？ assuming that you're close enough to be casual to each other.

Comment: I would love to see a comment or two from native speakers. Would anyone really say that? Sounds to me pretty awkward - in terms of flow - to omit は and end abruptly at どう at the same time.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to know too. I might be saying it wrong all along. I do hear 最近、どう？ from a friend but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: 最近、どう？is just asking for news, not necessary studies. "How have you been recently?"

Comment: Yes that's right. What I wanted to point out is that structurally, in terms of dropping particles, they look similar.